# Does Korean pronunciation sometimes differ in singing / rapping compared to spoken language?

Tags: pronunciation

I notice a lot of things are pronounced differently than they would in regular spoken speech. It could just be my ears. However, here are a few examples in BTS's DNA.

1:49 https://youtu.be/t9LC-YMxznE?t=109
As for "소스라치게", the "치게" sounds like "chege" when sung rather than "chige" as I'd expect for spoken language.

2:35 https://youtu.be/t9LC-YMxznE?t=155
As for "우연이 아니니까", the "아" sounds like "ya" when sung rather than "a" as I'd expect for spoken language.

Comment: The first one is for singers-only. So yes. That "치게" is different from what would be pronounced in a general conversation. For the latter, not really. I believe "이(ㅣ)" directly preceding any vowel always makes that thing sound as "y-". E.g. 디아: [diya] 기아: [kiya] 기우: [kiyu]

Comment: [A Study of Korean Diction for Choral Conductors (2017)](https://ir.ua.edu/bitstream/handle/123456789/3265/file_1.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) "[i]: Singing: Touch the tip of your tongue to the back of your lower teeth and open your mouth a little more than speaking".

Answer (score 2):

To my ears, some Korean rappers often Americanise their pronunciation a lot (in the same way that many British rock singers do). This does often mean putting an 'i' sound in front of other vowels to create a diphthong (which could on occasion turn an '아' into something more like '야'). 
An example of what I feel is very Americanised pronunciation is [this G-Dragon verse from 붉은노을](https://youtu.be/oJIWY9W5WAM?t=42).

However, my Korean friend thinks it's just trying to make it sound fun, rather than particularly American. So perhaps Korean singers and rappers sometimes just use affected and alternative pronunciations for interest in the same way that English vocalists do...

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this question may be on music : After skill man recorded singer's song, I suspect strongly that he
may give an influence on the recording.

(1) To me, 치게 is chige. When I listen "잘할게" (=I will do well)
which is a lyric, it sounds 자랄께 (And note that people speak [자랄께] for 잘할게)

But with high concentration, I listen 잘할게. But within 1 second, it is changed into 자랄께, as like an echo.

(2) 야니니까 : Singer may need high tone and clearness : vowel ㅣ is
one of most effective ways for high tone.

In another song, 넌 내 곁을 떠나 (You should get away from me) is [내 켜츨 떠나]. Correct one is
[내 켜틀 떠나].